# Can 'had' be used to describe something in the future?

Tags: sentence-construction, future

> If I ever lose my sanity, I will never find the exact point where the final blow had fallen'

Here, **'had'** likely describing something that might happened in the future. Is this correct? If so what grammatical rule is it following?

Comment: 'Had' is, in the future, describing something which happened in the past of that future. If I kill my dog tomorrow, next week I will regret that I had done so.

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said. But it would also be fine to use Simple Past in both those examples, and imho that's what the vast majority of native speakers would do: *If I ever lose my sanity, I will never find the exact point where the final blow **fell**, If I kill my dog tomorrow, next week I will regret that I **did** so.*